# How to plot a line graph in ggplot2 with With time interval on x axis and values on y axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot line graph with ggplot in r having only equally spaced time interval on x axis and values corresponding to time interval on y axis.

```
Time     Demand 
00:15  506.88 
00:30  506.88 
00:45  506.88 
1:00   506.88 
1:15   501.12 
1:30   501.12 
1:45   489.6 
2:00   501.12 
2:15   460.8 
2:30   455.04 
2:45   460.8 
3:00   460.8 
3:15   443.52
```

Comment: this should help you started: http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/geom_path.html

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `Time` column is going to be read in as a factor rather than as a number or a datetime. Quick way to get around this is to set `group = 1`. Assuming your dataframe is called `my_data`:

```
ggplot(data = my_data,
       aes(x = Time,
           y = Demand,
           group = 1)) + 
   geom_line()
```